# Protobuf.net 'IsDefined' logical bug?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

In the following code snippet I'm trying to use the 'IsDefined' method of a purpose-created model to see if I've already added the given type to the model. However, it always returns true, and inspection of the types known to the model after calling IsDefined shows that the type has been added to the model during the call. This seems to make IsDefined redundant, or am I missing something?

Version is 2.0.0.668.

```
    private static void FillSignatureModel(RuntimeTypeModel Model, Object SignedObject) {
        var lBinding = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;
        var lType = SignedObject.GetType();

        // Already sorted
        if (Model.IsDefined(lType)) return;

        var lProtoType = Model.Add(lType, false);
...
```

Secondary question: Is there a better way of reporting Protobuf.net bugs - not that I ever expected to need one ;-)

Comment: there is a bug tracker, if you are lucky enough to find one https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/list

Comment: Thanks @thumbmunkeys, though that's the Google part. The one I was looking for (and just found) is https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues

Comment: right, thats the right one: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/list